# flutter how to show first an interstitial ad through button and then go to new screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

i want to load an interstitial ad with a button in flutter. I want to show first the interstitial and then, when ad finish, go automaticaly to another screen, or load another thing.

I dont know how to make something like "interstitial.wait" to show first the ad, and when it will close run another thing.

this is my code:

```
onPressed: () {
   showInterstitialAd(); //this first
   launch(urlCourse.text); //when ad closed, run this
}
```

Comment: what if you add ```whenComplete()``` function in your ```showInterstitialAd()```

Comment: If your are planning to wait something until completed and you know how long it should take. You can use Future.delayed or something similiar related with Futures.

Comment: doen't exist to implement that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. We can make use of `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent`

this is an example:

```
 void showInterstitialAd() {
    if (interstitialAd == null) {
      print('trying to show before loading');
      return;
    }

    interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
        onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (ad) => print('ad showed $ad'),

        //when ad went closes
        onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
          //run something
          launch(urlCourse.text); 
          ad.dispose();
          createInterstitialAd();
        },
        onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) {
          ad.dispose();
          print('failed to show the ad $ad');

          createInterstitialAd();
        });

    interstitialAd!.show();
    interstitialAd = null;
  }
```